# Download operation (Pause & Resume) with AFNetowking 3.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsfilemanager, afnetworking-3

I have an application with a process reading a *.m3u8* file located in server and parse it. Then, later download chunk *.ts* files using `AFNetworking 3.x`

---

```
- (void)downloadChunks:(NSMutableArray *)streamingChunks directoryPath:(NSURL *)path{
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<streamingChunks.count; i++) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURL *tsDownloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [URL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent], streamingChunks[i]]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tsDownloadURL];

        self.downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
            return [path URLByAppendingPathComponent:[streamingChunks objectAtIndex:i]];
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
            self.progressView.progress += intermediate;
            NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);
        }];

        if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable) {
            [self.downloadTask resume];
        } else {
            [self.downloadTask suspend];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here, how to handle these scenarios:

- Do i have a method to pause the file download process?
- How to handle the internet connection or any other interruption?

Comment: You can refer to this topic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563753/afnetworking-not-resuming-download